# AtTiny85 reading from PIN

Tags: attiny, pins, port

First, I'm kinda new to this AVR world, please don't be too hard.

I'm running into a very simply problem. I'm trying to use the ATTiny85 inside the Arduino framework, but without the Arduino functions digitalRead or digitalWrite (too slow). I have **no** problem **writing** signal to pins (PORTB &= 0b00000001), But whatever I try, I'm **not able** to **READ** from the pin (PINB & 0b0000001).

However, this is not entirely true. whatever I try (PINB & 0b000001, PINB & 0b000010, PINB & 0b000100, I'm always value reading from the **PIN 0** (physical pin 5). Does anyone have try to read the ATTiny pin without the Arduino function ?
I'm simply trying to do digital read here. *(no analog)*
Here a sample code which reproduce the problem.

```
  DDRB = 0b00001000; // set the LED pin as output.
  while (1) 
  {

    if ( PINB & 0b00000010 != 0) // read the PIN to check if the button is pressed.
    {
      PORTB = 0b00000000; //Turn Off the LED when the button is pressed
    }
    else
    {
      PORTB = 0b00001000;  //Turn on one LED by default
    }
  }  
}
```

Comment: [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). `!=` comes before `&`. Brackets are your friend.

Comment: Damn, you are right.... If this is my only problem, I good for a triple head-bashing on the desk.
And you know what is funny, I program in C++ for more than 20 years. But because it is in a context where I'm not comfortable, I immediately put the blame on the hardware ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It all comes down to [Operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence).

In C/C++, `!=` is evaluated before `&`. As a result, your condition is effectively:

```
if ( PINB & (2 == 0))
```

Which it should be clear that this is always going to be 0 - `2 == 0` is always 0.

You have two choices:

1. Use something with a higher precedence in the if statement, for example `()`:

   ```
   if ( (PINB & 2) != 0 )
   ```

   Which will work as expected - the parenthesis are evaluated before the `!=`.
2. Rely on the fact that any non-zero value is considered true:

   ```
   if (PINB & 2) //True is anything non-zero.
   ```

Comment: Shame on me... yes you are right. It was as simple as this... Lesson learned, check the code twice before putting the blame on the hardware.